# Sony Alpha R 7 Camera - - On Camera App

Tags: android, scripting, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I have a Sony Alpha 7R Camera and look for information about the "build in" application support. What are those apps, android based? I there information public about how to create and install your own camera app  -- NOT talking about the remote api.

The few available apps are kind of primitive and limited, in particular I'd like to create a more versatile "Interval timer" app -- the time lapse thing is kind of too simple for my purpose.

To be particular: versatile bracketing, absolute start/stop times, complex shooting programs with pre programmed ISO, Shutter, bracketing etc. for a series for programmed interval shooting, or simply as fast as possible... As an example -- I just suffered "lost valuable time" shooting a Eclipse as I had to reconfigure/switch modes, etc.

Ideal would be a scenario I could upload a shooting script to the app on the camera.

Comment: See: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/59226/67934

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is that you can build applications for the Camera API using many different methods. When you create an application for the Camera API you are just making API calls to the camera while your code is connected to the camera Wifi somehow. In the end the easiest way to distribute your code is using smartphones as it will work for IOS, Windows, etc.. as well as Android, but you are not limited to these technologies. Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: Thank for the response. My point is --- I would love to avoid the need or to depend on any external devices, wired and WiFi connections as the camera seams to offer some kind of "app" interface naively. Less clutter and more reliable in the field. A awesome scenario I could imagine would be a scripting interface/app (python like for example) ON the camera what takes and can store on the camera for later recall and execution. The script (or app) collection could for example located on the memory card in dedicated folder.

Comment: A recent problem I had (at least not ideal) was while shooting the Eclipse over the USA. I was running the simple time-lapse app for the partial phase a photo every 18s. Then had to exit the app (costs valuable time already) and switch modes to manual/bracketing for the totality... and then back to time lapse. All in one program would have been ideal as absolute times were known exactly.

Comment: ok I understand. Unfortunately we do not have an API that supports this functionality.

Comment: So the camera "build-in" app functionality is completed "closed" development only, is that right?

Comment: Right, we don't currently have an API that allows you to create a built in app.

Comment: I understand. What I think a really valuable "Sony made" on camera app would be a app that can interpret a simple camera action script to pre-program and automatize complex shooting plan:

Comment: The script may also allow to hook a callback-function to any camera button and allow to output text/info on the display as well!